# How to invoke both of the class functions with same name with a single object?

Tags: c++

I have to write two statements by using object S from void main to invoke function 1 and 2. But the object is of type SECOND. Both the functions have the exact same name and i have to call them from Same object S from main....  The code is

```
class FIRST
{
    int num1;
public:
    FIRST()
    {
        num1 = 1;
    }
    void display() /* function 1 */
    {
        cout << num1 << endl;
    }
};

class SECOND
{
    int num2;
public:
    SECOND()
    {
        num2 = 2;
    }
    void display() /*  function 2 */
    {
        cout << num2 << endl;
    }
};

void main()
{
    SECOND S;
    statement 1 /*What can they be? */
    statement 2
    getch();
}
```

Comment: To invoke a class's member function, you need an instance of that class. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Can you modify the classes?

Comment: Why must you do this? Is it just a puzzle? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Seriously, take a different C++ course or get a different reference.  The `main` function's return type is `int`, not `void`.  Any assignment (requirements) that mentions `void main` is an indication of poor instruction (teaching) quality.

Answer (score 0):

Since FIRST and SECOND are two completely separate and unrelated classes, it's not possible to call the display() method of the FIRST class on an instance of the SECOND class.

However, if SECOND is derived from FIRST

```
class SECOND : public FIRST
```

then you should be able to do:

```
S.display(); // Calls function2
S.FIRST::display(); // Calls function1(Base class version)
```